# Does Uzbek have irregular verbs?

Tags: conjugation

Does Uzbek language have any irregular verbs regarding conjugation?

If so could you provide these verbs or a source?

Comment: What are your criteria for "irregularity"?

Comment: Uzbek is extremely regular, there being no exceptions to remember. However, Uzbek is a rather old language with the well-developed literature, and even more importantly,  vast territorial extent and contacts with different kindred Turkic languages which can interfere with the official norm. Just note that making the causative voice form of the verb is not very straightforward since different verbs use different suffixes for this: _-t, -ir, -kiz/-gaz_, etc. But if you look at it as at word-building, not as at conjugation, then Uzbek conjugation can be considered perfectly regular.